# Animate Views when Activity starts in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-animation

I am finishing `FlashScreen` and starting `MainActivity` using `startActivity();`
and I want to slide linearLayout of MainActivity from left to right slowly like an animation. But it's not happening. At first the linearLayout loads up and then it performs the animation so it's of no use.
Here's my code :

**slide_from_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**MainAcitivity.java**

```
Animation animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_from_left);
mLinearLayoutParent.startAnimation(animFadein);
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are sliding from any side, then this `View` should be "slided out" in this direction when initialised (on start). consider adding proper param to XML, in your case it would be `android:translationX` for `mLinearLayoutParent`. use some very high value to be shure that this `View` isn't visible, as in here you can't set translation by % of view like in `<translate` tag. when anim starts then `android:fromXDelta="-100%"` line will move `View` to this position (exact `-100%` of width, as initial for animation) at very beginning of animation

Answer (score 1):

To animate every activity when it opens or closes, you need to create four animation files (namely : **slide_in_right**, **slide_in_left**, ***slide_out_right***, **slide_out_left**). After creating these animations, you will have to add the following code in your values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="android:customActivityAnimation"     parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
<item name="activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
<item name="activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item> 
<item name="activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item> 
<item name="activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item> 

</style>
```

After that in your default application theme add this style :

```
<style  name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/customActivityAnimation</style>
```